# set a click event dynamically to dojo button

Tags: button, dojo, dijit.form

I m trying to set a on click event dynamically to a dijit/form/Button.
But, the method I m trying doesn't seem to work.

```
<button id = "newActButton" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button"
    type = "button" 
    data-dojo-props="iconClass: 'newActButtonIcon', label: 'New Act'"></button>


dijit.byId("newActButton").set("onClick", newActButtonOnClick());
```

I have a function newActButtonOnClick(), which I want to fire.

Comment: What version of Dojo?

Comment: any reason you dont what to use the dojo/on event handler?

Comment: I just don't see the difference yet. I m new to dojo. Any particular advantage of using dojo/on event handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try something like this:

```
require(["dojo/on", "dojo/dom", "dojo/domReady!"],
    function(on, dom) {
        var newActButton = dom.byId("newActButton");

        on(newActButton, "click", newActButtonOnClick);
});
```

[Here's tutorial](https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.7/events/)

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lifus/BUX4b/)

Comment: A couple of suggestions-- use `dijit.byId` since the button being worked with is a dijit widget, and use `Widget#on`rather than the global on module (`dijit.byId('myButton').on('click',function(){});`

Comment: @BuffaloBuffalo Are your suggestions related to 1.8 onward? Well OP uses Dojo 1,7 and dijit._Widget#on [appeared in Dojo 1.8](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/1.8/dijit/_Widget) and [won't work on 1.7](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/1.7/dijit/_Widget), I'm afraid.

Comment: oops, you are correct.  I guess I didn't really start using the `on`/`emit` event style until 1.8 (compared with the dojo/connect api).

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because you have an error in your code (by.Id VERSUS byId):

```
dijit.by.Id("newActButton").set("onClick", newActButtonOnClick());
```

should be

```
dijit.byId("newActButton").set("onClick", newActButtonOnClick());
```

**EDIT**

Try this:

```
require(["dojo/parser", "dijit/form/Button"]);

<button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" type="button">Click me too!
    <script type="dojo/on" data-dojo-event="click" data-dojo-args="evt">
        require(["dojo/dom"], function(dom){
            dom.byId("result2").innerHTML += "Thank you! ";
        });
    </script>
</button>
<div id="result2"></div>
```

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. Its not working with dijit.byId as well